# Running periodically background function in class initializer

Tags: python-3.x, multithreading, python-asyncio, background-process

I am trying to interface some Api which requires an auth token using asyncio.

I have a method inside the ApiClient class for obtaining this token.

```
class ApiClient:    
    def __init__(self):
        self._auth_token = None
        # how to invoke _keep_auth_token_alive in the background?

    async def _keep_auth_token_alive(self):
        while True:
            await self._set_auth_token()
            await asyncio.sleep(3600)
```

The problem is, that every hour I need to recall this function in order to maintain a valid token because it refreshes every hour (without this I will get 401 after one hour).

How can I make this method invoke every hour in the background starting at the initializing of ApiClient?

(The _set_auth_token method makes an HTTP request and then self._auth_token = res.id_token)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use an asyncio library, your program needs to run inside the asyncio event loop. Assuming that's already the case, you need to use `asyncio.create_task`:

```
class ApiClient:    
    def __init__(self):
        self._auth_token = None
        asyncio.create_task(self._keep_auth_token_alive())
```

Note that the auth token will not be available upon a call to `ApiClient()`, it will get filled no earlier than the first `await`, after the background task has had a chance to run. To fix that, you can make `_set_async_token` public and await it explicitly:

```
client = ApiClient()
await client.set_async_token()
```

To make the usage more ergonomic, you can implement an async context manager. For example:

```
class ApiClient:    
    def __init__(self):
        self._auth_token = None

    async def __aenter__(self):
        await self._set_auth_token()
        self._keepalive_task = asyncio.create_task(self._keep_auth_token_alive())

    async def __aexit__(self, *_):
        self._keepalive_task.cancel()

    async def _keep_auth_token_alive(self):
        # modified to sleep first and then re-acquire the token
        while True:
            await asyncio.sleep(3600)    
            await self._set_auth_token()
```

Then you use `ApiClient` inside an `async with`:

```
async with ApiClient() as client:
    ...
```

This has the advantage of reliably canceling the task once the client is no longer needed. Since Python is garbage-collected and doesn't support deterministic destructors, this would not be possible if the task were created in the constructor.

Comment: What do you mean by " it will get filled no earlier than the first await"? 
I added the create_task in the init and I want to make sure that the auth_token will be filled before any other request (I did client = ApiClient() and then I want await client.do_somthing_that_requires_the_auth_token()).
Are there options besides context manager?

Comment: @omerbarlev *What do you mean by " it will get filled no earlier than the first await"?* - I mean, if you write `client = ApiClient(); assert client._auth_token is not None`, the assertion will fail. The token will become available once the created task has had a chance to execute. *Are there options besides context manager* - yes. you can make `set_auth_token` public and just await it after the constructor.  (This is mentioned in the answer.)